# If/else statement comparing numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am writing jquery and i need to change colors if great than 730 days.. between 730 and 183 days ... ect. well its not working on my page if there something wrong with my if else statement?Here is all of the jquery but I just need help with the if/else part.I am very new to this and any help is great.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
'use strict';

var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
        "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ],

    dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],

    newDate = new Date();

$('#safetyRecord').hide();

$('#today').text(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + "," + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getDate() + "," + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());

$('#checkRecord').click(function () {

    var dateOfLastAccident = new Date($('#dateOfLastAccident').val());

    var today = new Date(),

        daysSinceLastAccident = Math.floor((today.getTime() - dateOfLastAccident.getTime()) / (25 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

    $('#daysSinceLastAccident').text(daysSinceLastAccident);

    $('#safetyRecord').show();

if (daysSinceLastAccident >= parseInt(730)){
    {
    $('#safetyRecord').addClass('great');
    }

else if (daysSinceLastAccident >=730<=183)
{
    $('#safetyRecord').addClass('good');
}

else if (daysSinceLastAccident >=183<=60) 
{
    $('#safetyRecord').addClass('.marginal');
}
else if (daysSinceLastAccident >=60<= 14) 
{
    $('#safetyRecord').addClass('.poor');
}
else (daysSinceLastAccident < 14)
{
    $('#safetyRecord').addClass('.disaster');
}


});
```

});

Comment: try wrapping your number variable in `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

Comment: You're missing parenthesis in all the conditions, and you can't chain conditions like that, you have to use the `&&` or `||` operator. Try validating your code first here http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: What does this mean? `daysSinceLastAccident >=730<=183`

Comment: The first if condition (daysSinceLastAccident >= parseInt(730)) has an extra opening curly brace.

Answer (score 1):

Your if conditions are broken. You have:

```
else if (daysSinceLastAccident >=730<=183
```

when you should have something like

```
else if ((daysSinceLastAccident < 730) && (daysSinceLastAccident>=183)) {
```

You'll need to change them all, and watch the direction of your comparisons too. You won't find much that is `> 730` and also `<= 183`

Comment: woops on the paranthese i just changed them all to the above and it is not working.

Comment: Well, 'it's not working' is a vague term. There could be many other problems. You haven't posted the HTML or CSS that this relates to, so it's quite possible that  jQuery selectors are wrong, or your CSS doesn't contain the rules, or some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really make any sense:

```
else if (daysSinceLastAccident >=730<=183
```

If your first condition is false, you can just fall through to the next one.

```
if (daysSinceLastAccident >= 730) {
{
    $('#safetyRecord').addClass('great');
}
else if (daysSinceLastAccident >= 183) 
{
    $('#safetyRecord').addClass('good');
}
// and so on...
```

You don't need any kind of `&&` logic because your ranges don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible `daysSinceLastAccident >=183<=60` and you have alot of coding errors with your parentheses and curly brackets.. BTW i hope you know how to use `'use strict'`